# Appending( not adding) Items of an objects in a list

Tags: c#, list, object, append, addition

This is one of my doubts:
If I have a class like ABC and it has three items like A,B,C (string type).
I run a loop for A then add obj in List.
Again I run a loop for B then add obj to List. and same for C as well.

Now this is not what I wanted. I never wanted to add obj after each loop. Instead I want to add them at the end so that list contains only one count instead of three.
Is it possible?

I know how to add list to another etc, but I am looking to append( not add).
Update:
Well I had already mentioned this in my question and I am explaining further.

```
public List<ABC> Method()
    {
     //Linq Query to get records
        List<ABC> Lst = new List<ABC>();
        foreach (var result in Linq)
        {
            ABC obj = new ABC (); 
       //here I make sub query to get A and add obj in list and adding in list
        }
        foreach (var result1 in Linq)
        {
            ABC obj = new ABC (); 
       //here I make sub query to get B and add obj in list and adding in list
        }
       foreach (var result1 in Linq)
        {
            ABC obj = new ABC (); 
       //here I make sub query to get C and add obj in list and adding in list
        }
        return Lst;
    }

In my List I get:
Count1=A,null,null
Count2=null,B,null
Count3=null,null,C
```

I wanted to get

```
Count1=A,B,C.
```

Comment: add some related code, otherwise the question is confusing

Comment: The `Add` method *is* appending; I think you need to clarify the distinction you are looking for. Re "I never wanted to add obj after each loop" - then why did you add obj after each loop, if that isn't what you wanted to do?

Comment: do you mean something like `myList.Add(aFound + bFound + cFound);`??

Comment: I got a way by not creating object again and again but simply adding the same in the last when I got all values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the values to be unique you could use HashSet, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx

If you still need a list, you could transform at the end using ToList.

Comment: if you use a hash-set, it must be noted that there is no guarantee of any order

Comment: good call, in that case, a SortedSet<T> may be more appropriate if order is to be preserved and you can use .NET 4 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx

Comment: sorted order is not the same as insertion order :)